# When drawing five cards, what is the probability of exactly 4 diamonds without replacement?

Tags: probability

I have that the correct equation is 5C4 x 1/4 x 12/51 x 11/50 x 10/49 x 38/48

I understand the parts with the probabilities, but why is it 5C4?

When I first did the problem, I thought it was 13C4 because there are 13 diamonds to choose from. Why is that wrong?

Comment: Why $38$? There are $39$ non-diamonds.

Comment: There's more than one way to do things. And that is especially true in probability.  5C4 refers to which of the 4 ot of 5 cards are diamonds.  13C 4 refers to which four diamonds or in your hand.  Both may or may not relevent depending on how you set up the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> When I first did the problem, I thought it was 13C4 because there are 13 diamonds to choose from. Why is that wrong?

It is not wrong.

$$\dfrac{{}^{13}C_{4}\cdot{}^{39}C_1}{^{52}C_5} ~=~ \dfrac{\dfrac{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot 10}{4~\cdot ~3~\cdot ~2~\cdot~ 1}\cdot \dfrac {39}{1}}{\dfrac{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}{5\cdot~4~\cdot ~3~\cdot ~2~\cdot~ 1}} ~=~ {}^{5}C_4\cdot \dfrac{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot 10\cdot 39}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}$$

The far left measures the probability for selecting four from thirteen diamonds and one from 38 non-diamonds when selecting any five from all fifty-two cards.

The far right counts the ways to select a place for the non-diamond, and multiplies this by the proability for selecting four diamond and one one diamond *in a particular order*.

The middle demonstrates why these are equal.

Comment: shouldn't it be 39c1 because you have to choose 1 card from 52-13=39? or I got it wrong? (I'm referring to the left side of the equation. upper right only); there rest is ok

Comment: @adhg.  Yes.  Yes, it should.  Correction made.

Comment: Typographical error:  You meant to say $39$ non-diamonds.